WPF Webbrowser display PdfDocument - Security warning download file instead of open it
Hope someone can help me, I am working on a WPF application and need to display a previously created pdf document on a preview display, for that I am using the WebBrowser control. The Document is succesfully saved on a public folder on my pc, but when trying to navigate to that pdf document, or event setting the source of the webbrowser the browser just wants to download the file instead of displaying it, can someone explain how to deactivate this?
Download screenshot
I tried to create a stream and display it, also I tried to convert the pdf into a base64string, that was too long to be displayed.
browser.Navigate("file:///" + @"C:\Users\Public\Documents\TempFiles\document.pdf");


You should use the modern Edge (Chromium) based browser integration WebView2 instead of the old Internet Explorer based WebBrowser.
XAML
xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"

<wpf:WebView2 x:Name="BrowserView"
              Source="C:\Users\Public\Documents\TempFiles\document.pdf" />

C#

string pdfFilePath = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\TempFiles\document.pdf";
this.BrowserView.Source = new Uri(pdfFilePath, UriKind.Absolute);

